# matrix multiplication but with variable dimensions

Tags: matrix-multiplication

I'm having difficulty with my matrix multiplication here.

```
for(i=0;i<row;i++){ /* matrix multiplication process */
    for(j=0;j<col;j++){
        matrix3[i][j]=0;
```

the problem is with this part right here. The thing about matrix trans[col][row] is it's matrix[row][col] but transposed. And the values of variables row and col are determined by the user. So now, the problem is I can't seem to figure out how to limit the variable k in this for loop here.

```
        for(k=0;k<row;k++){ /* summation and multiplication of elements */
            matrix3[i][j] += matrix[i][k]*trans[k][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiplying a `row x col` matrix by a `col x row` matrix will give you a `row x row` matrix. So, `i` and `j` are `[0..row)`, and `k` is `[0..col)`. You can just look at your expression:

```
            matrix3[i][j] += matrix[i][k]*trans[k][j];
```

and ask yourself: “In `matrix[i][k]`, what is the range for `k`, given that it's the second dimension of `matrix`?” Similar questions will help for other variables.